# KeyError: 'Name' Python dicts and AWS sdk

Tags: python, json, dictionary, amazon-web-services

Soo here is a piece of my code form yesterday, regardless of not being able to get `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to continue cooperating, I have hardcoded some of our AWS credentials to test...
Anywho, yesterday this worked fine and it output the `serverInfo.json` info as such:

```
[
    {
        "develop-env": {
            "id": "i-xxxx",
            "imageId": "ami-xxxxx",
            "ipAddress": "54.xxx.xx.xxx.xx",
            "keyPair": xxx,
            "publicDNSname": "ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com",
            "region": "us-east-1c",
            "size/type": "t1.micro"
        }
    },
    {
        "deploymentTesting": {
            "id": "i-xxxxxx",
            "imageId": "ami-xxxxx",
            "ipAddress": "5x.x.xx.xxx",
            "keyPair": "xxxxx",
            "publicDNSname": "ec2-xx-x-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com",
            "region": "us-east-1b",
            "size/type": "t1.micro"
        }
    },
```

.. And so forth, I think you get the idea.
This is the code that was run to create that:

```
#from django.conf import settings
#import gomoto.settings
import json
import boto
import os

# os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "gomoto.settings")

#aki = settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
#sak = settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
aki = 'xxxxx'
sak = 'xxxxx'

# clears all the content in serverInfo.json
with open('serverInfo.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    for item in data:
        del item
f.close()

# object that holds the connection instance.
c = boto.connect_ec2(aki, sak)
# retrive all the instances associated with this account
allInstances = c.get_only_instances()

serverContent = []

# iterate through instance objects, building the json object and inserting the proper instance attributes
for i in allInstances:
    instanceContent = {}
    instanceContent ={
        i.tags['Name']: {
            'id': i.id,
            'publicDNSname': i.public_dns_name,
            'region': str(i._placement),
            'ipAddress': i.ip_address,
            'imageId': i.image_id,
            'size/type': i.instance_type,
            'keyPair': i.key_name,
            # 'groups': i.groups,
            # 'groupName': i.group_name
        }
    }
    # append the py dict to the py list
    serverContent.append(instanceContent)

# json dump the contents of serverContent array
with open('serverInfo.json', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(
        json.dumps(serverContent, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
    )
f.close()
```

Today, in doing further testing, the script does not run and instead produces this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "update.py", line 42, in <module>
    'groupName': i.group_name
KeyError: 'Name'
```

Can someone point me in the right direction so I can troubleshoot this? This is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: At line 32 you access `i.tags['Name']`, and the error shows one or more `i.tags` do not have a key `'Name'`

Comment: @starrify - I'm not sure I follow what you are saying.. However, get_only_instances() returns 'Instances' objects which have 'tags' objects that I was able to access as a list... Can you a bit more specific? Thank you

Comment: so the problem was that i.tags['Name'] was an empty object and there was no logic to handle that.